# Don't format multiline 'If' statements to single line in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, code-formatting

I've searched with on google without success by now. Is it possible to disable the formatting of multiline 'if' statements to single line. I write PHP code and have not tested if this happens to other languages in Netbeans.

Original:

```
if ($checkOne->very_long_function()
    || $checkTwo->you_dont_want_this()
    || $checkThree->in_one_line())
```

After the default formatting of Netbeans the statement is in a single line

```
if ($checkOne->very_long_function() || $checkTwo->you_dont_want_this() || $checkThree->in_one_line())
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to

```
"Tools" -> "Options" -> "Editor" -> "Formatting"
```

Select the category "Wrapping" and scroll down to "Wrap After Binary Operators" and check it.

Netbeans will not change multiline if-statements anymore.